# Replace null with empty string value in multidimensional array php

Tags: php, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have one multidimensional array with null key value. How to replace null to empty string in multidimensional array php ? my array is

```
"result": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "first_name": "Kishan",
      "last_name": "Patel",
      "profile_picture": null,
      "email": "imkishanpatel107@gmail.com",
      "birthdate": "1992-07-10",
      "gender": "male",
      "nickname": "KK",
      "town": null,
      "state": "58",
      "bio": "123",
      "zipcode": "395006",
      "radius": "12356",
      "favroiteteam": "2",
      "latitude": "1.25456",
      "longitude": "4.5658787",
      "message_enable": "0",
      "ratting_enable": "0",
      "add_friend_enable": "0",
      "interested_in": null,
      "user_sport": [
        {
          "sport": {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "Basketball",
            "image": "",
            "no_of_player": "9",
            "is_active": "1"
          },
          "sportPosition": {
            "id": "1",
            "sport_id": "3",
            "position_name": "Point Guard"
          },
          "skill_level": {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Novice"
          }
        },
        {
          "sport": {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Baseball",
            "image": "",
            "no_of_player": "10",
            "is_active": "1"
          },
          "sportPosition": {
            "id": "6",
            "sport_id": "2",
            "position_name": "Pitcher"
          },
          "skill_level": {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "Advanced"
          }
        },
        {
          "sport": {
            "id": "8",
            "name": "Roller Hockey",
            "image": "",
            "no_of_player": "0",
            "is_active": "1"
          },
          "sportPosition": {
            "id": "15",
            "sport_id": "8",
            "position_name": "Forward"
          },
          "skill_level": {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Novice"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: while using this array you just write the if conditions ..

Answer (score 1):

Simply put a loop and check if null with foreach

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (is_null($value)) $array[$key] = "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Kishan Kikani you can not replace null to '' because both consider as empty value that in the output of your array there will be empty value at the place of null or '' you have to assign something to replace your value in above array like below you have both ways(your and mine) you can do:

```
<?php
$result =   array("result"=> 
                array(
                  "id"=> "1",
                  "first_name"=> "Kishan",
                  "last_name"=> "Patel",
                  "profile_picture"=> null,
                  "email"=> "imkishanpatel107@gmail.com",
                  "birthdate"=> "1992-07-10",
                  "gender"=> "male",
                  "nickname"=> "KK",
                  "town"=> null,
                  "state"=> "58",
                  "bio"=> "123",
                  "zipcode"=> "395006",
                  "radius"=> "12356",
                  "favroiteteam"=> "2",
                  "latitude"=> "1.25456",
                  "longitude"=> "4.5658787",
                  "message_enable"=> "0",
                  "ratting_enable"=> "0",
                  "add_friend_enable"=> "0",
                  "interested_in"=> null,
                  "user_sport"=> 
                    array(
                      "sport"=> array(
                        "id"=> "3",
                        "name"=> "Basketball",
                        "image"=> "",
                        "no_of_player"=> "9",
                        "is_active"=> "1"
                      ),
                      "sportPosition"=> array(
                        "id"=> "1",
                        "sport_id"=> "3",
                        "position_name"=> "Point Guard"
                      ),
                      "skill_level"=> array(
                        "id"=> "1",
                        "name"=> "Novice"
                      )
                    ),
                    array(
                      "sport"=> array(
                        "id"=> "2",
                        "name"=> "Baseball",
                        "image"=> "",
                        "no_of_player"=> "10",
                        "is_active"=> "1"
                      ),
                      "sportPosition"=> array(
                        "id"=> "6",
                        "sport_id"=> "2",
                        "position_name"=> "Pitcher"
                      ),
                      "skill_level"=> array(
                        "id"=> "3",
                        "name"=> "Advanced"
                      )
                    ),
                    array(
                      "sport"=> array(
                        "id"=> "8",
                        "name"=> "Roller Hockey",
                        "image"=> "",
                        "no_of_player"=> "0",
                        "is_active"=> "1"
                      ),
                      "sportPosition"=> array(
                        "id"=> "15",
                        "sport_id"=> "8",
                        "position_name"=> "Forward"
                      ),
                      "skill_level"=> array(
                        "id"=> "1",
                        "name"=> "Novice"
                      )
                    )
                )
            );
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result); // BEFORE


foreach($result as $rsKey => $rs){
    foreach($rs as $key => $value){
        if(is_null($value)){
            $result[$rsKey][$key] = "";
        }
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result); // after replace only null to "" but there will be a empty space in the values



foreach($result as $rsKey => $rs){
    foreach($rs as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value)){   
            foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
                foreach ($v as $k1 => $v1) {
                    if(empty($v1)){
                        $result[$rsKey][$key][$k][$k1] = "level2";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            if(is_null($value)){
                $result[$rsKey][$key] = "level1";
            }
        }
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result); // after replace whole array empty values
```

try any one you want (y)

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array(
          "key1"=>"value1",
          "key2"=>null,
          "key3"=>array(
                 "subkey1"=>null, 
                 "subkey2"=>"subvalue2"),
          "key4"=>null);

    echo json_encode(replace_null_with_empty_string($arr));

   function replace_null_with_empty_string($array)
    {
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) 
        {
            if(is_array($value))
                $array[$key] = replace_null_with_empty_string($value);
            else
            {
                if (is_null($value))
                    $array[$key] = "";
            }
        }
        return $array;
    }
```

Comment: Please try to avoid just dumping code as an answer and try to explain what it does and why. Your code might not be obvious for people who do not have the relevant coding experience. Please edit your answer to include [clarification, context and try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

Piggybacking off @Atish's answer... I cleaned it up and made it simpler. This loops through the array and alters the value reference (&), then loops thru each next dimension of the array using recursion. @Daidon's answer only loops thru the first dimension.

The new function looks like this...

```
    function null2empty($array){
        foreach ($array as &$value) {
            $value = (is_array($value)) ? null2empty($value) : $value;
            $value = (is_null($value)) ? "" : $value;
        }
        return $array;
    }
```

to use it, you would call it like this...

```
$profile_array = null2empty($profile_array);
```